# Apparmor: does complain mode enable capability dac_override?

Tags: ipsec, apparmor

I'm trying to adjust an AppArmor profile after I found [some guidance](https://review.openstack.org/#/c/144391/) that it should be disabled for my use-case (not too happy running an IPSec daemon naked).

So I've tried to put it in `complain` mode and this fixed the issue, but without actually revealing what the cause was; I had expected `aa-logprof` to [help me there](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Failures#Debugging_an_AppArmor_problem) but it came back empty.

Digging a little further, I discovered this smoking gun in `/var/log/messages` (before enabling `complain` mode):

```
type=1400 audit(1470858266.974:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/ipsec/charon" pid=27117 comm="charon" capability=1  capname="dac_override"
```

Enabling `complain` mode yields:

```
type=1400 audit(1470855949.106:69): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/ipsec/charon" pid=4674 comm="charon" capability=1  capname="dac_override"
```

So it looks like `capability dac_override` is what's missing (and indeed, if I manually add it to the profile, it works).

But I'm puzzled as to why this wasn't explicitly revealed by `complain`.  Does `complain` transparently enable `dac_override`?

I'm rather new to AppArmor; I did spend a fair bit of time today trying to parse the documentation but couldn't find any reference to this behaviour...

(apparmor 2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5.3 on Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0-92)